Unable to connect Einstein File with Salesforce Flow
I am building a proof of concept trying to connect Einstein bot with salesforce flow connected to Mulesoft IDP via external API call. The user will upload a document directly in the chat of the enhanced einstein bot. This document will be sent to autolaunched salesforce flow which will then send it via https request to mulesoft IDP for processing and return the document id to the user in chat which can be used later for querying.
However, when I upload a file using File component, it is saved as a custom id list type variable. I am unable to create a similar type input variable for the flow so I can access details of this file in the flow and send it to IDP via http request. I have tried access the record type content version list variable but it is not compatible with the default File output variable of ID List type.
Is this use case possible with the current version of the salesforce developer environment? If yes, kindly let me know how I can do it.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

So, I had a call with salesforce through partner channel and according to them, this is use case not possible currently as the APIs to connect the auto-launched flow with file component are not (yet) implemented.
